# Why this function does not work on iOS cordova platform while its fully working on android platform?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova for my application. All functions are working fine on both platforms android/iOS, all but ONE. It works on android but not iOS. When I call my function, I'm getting no errors just like android but its doesn't work.

The function that doesn't work, is the loadPicture(), for changing profile picture, its working fine on android, its gets to photo library, you select an image, upload it to server with file transfer, and reload the page and thats it.

With the iOS version, its doesn't work

This is my function, I'll provide other details if needed. I appreciate any kind of help  :)

```
function loadPicture()
{
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
   sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, targetWidth: 200, targetHeight: 200
 });

  function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var myDate = new Date();
    var date = myDate.getFullYear() +"-" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)  +"-" + myDate.getUTCDate() +"_" + myDate.getHours() + "-" + myDate.getMinutes() + "-" + myDate.getSeconds();
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");

    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = "photo-" + userid + "-" + date + ".jpeg";
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    var params = {};
    params.userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
    params.date = date;
    params.account = "user";
    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://62.210.192.92/AE/web/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
    navigator.notification.alert("Changement effectué", "", "Photo de profile");
    reload();
    var win = function (r) {}
    var fail = function (error) {}
  }
  function onFail(error) {}
}
```

Here's my web inspection errors : I'm ok with some of them, and its not related with this problem 'i suppose ', the calendar error and the JSON parse error, the others I dont know :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSORI.png)

Comment: Did you inspected the code in safari web inspector? There could be some console errors for sure.

Comment: Add more details. What don't work? It enter into the onSuccess function?

Comment: Exactly what you are getting in your imageURI in IOS ?

Comment: Yes, i  did inspection with safari web browser, i have some errors sure, but not related with this problem as it's the same error as with android chrome web inspector, anyway, ill upload them in the original poste, you'll see, thank you very much for your concern

Comment: Iv' uploaded more details for my problem :)

Comment: as for the imageURI, even if it enter onSucess, it does not upload any image to the server